# PyMongo Getting a filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON Error

Tags: python, mongodb

Below is the python code I am trying to run. But, am getting an error which says...

```
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping



query = db.collections.table.find({ "$and": [ { "time": { "$gte" : 5000 } }, { "time" : { "$lte": 10000 } }, { "blt_id":20} ] })

projection = db.collections.table.find({ "alt_id": 1, "time": 1, "__id": 0})

for doc in db.collections.table.find(query, projection):
    print(doc)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query` and `projection` should just be `dict`s; with some optimisations your code should be:

```
query = {"time": {"$gte": 5000, "$lte": 10000}, "blt_id": 20}
projection = {"alt_id": 1, "time": 1, "_id": 0}

for doc in db.collections.table.find(query, projection):
    print(doc)
```